# Creating a frame sleeve for an LED lamp in Blender

Tags: edit-mode

I am trying to make my granddaughter an LED lamp of the Little Mermaid. I have tried many different things and watched a ton of videos, but I'm just not good enough in Blender to figure out how to do this. I am going to print the Little Mermaid with the first 4 layers being white, and the next x amount of layers black, to show the outline of the mermaid. That's the easy part.

The part I just can't seem to accomplish is to make a frame to put the LED lights in. It will conform to the shape of the mermaid print, and will extend for about 10mm around the perimeter of the white mermaid. There will also be a thin (4mm or so) inner "shelf" around the inside edge of the frame, that the mermaid print will lay on. The print will then be flush with the frame. The frame will be a few inches thick to accommodate the lights, a small controller and give it some depth. This is the print I will be using:

[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm sorry, don't mean to be rude - but all the information on how you print the mermaid etc. doesn't help anything for this question. Do I basically get you right, you want to create an object in Blender that has the contour of the mermaid, with a defined thickness for outlining the shape? I guess that depends a lot on which file formats of the mermaid you have available and which software - because I really think the contour is better done in a different propram than Blender.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I am trying to make a contoured case that the mermaid print will fit into. I got the mermaid as a .PNG file, and then converted it to STL. I primarily use Blender and Photoshop, but have also explored other software. Whatever gets the job done! Thank You.